# Extending code to compute maximum dot product for arbitrary number of vectors

Tags: python, list, dot-product

How can I modify my code so that the `max_dot_p` works if there are more than 3 vectors in the list? (`dot_p` is dot product)

Here is what I have tried:

```
def dot_p(vector1, vector2):
    total = 0
    for x, y in zip(vector1, vector2):
        total += x * y

    return total

def max_dot_p(vectors):

    product = []
    for i in range(len(vectors)):
        for j in range(len(vectors)):
            dot_p = dot_product(vectors[i] , vectors[j])
            product.append(dot_p)
            continue
    

        max_product = max(product) 

        return max_product   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    vectors = [[5, 6], [13, 1], [3, 1]
    print(max_dot_p(vectors))
```

It does not give me the expected answer, although it does run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to select two vectors to pass into your dot product function, and then take the maximum value across all invocations to your dot product function:

```py
from itertools import combinations
def max_dot_p(vectors):
    return max(dot_p(x, y) for x, y in combinations(vectors, k=2))
```

Comment: okok i will try that ! I did not learn it in class though, so I am not sure if there might be another way to go around that ?

Comment: You can use a nested for-loop, though that might be more verbose.

Comment: I tried :
'''
    product = []
    for i in range(len(vectors)):
        for j in range(len(vectors)):
            dot_p = dot_product(i ,j)
            product += dot_p
            continue
        

    max_product = max(product)  
    
    return max_product 
'''
but it goes no where

Comment: Use `.append()` rather than `+=`, but otherwise at a first glance it looks fine (?)

Comment: I get a TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration (??)
in relation to the first def posted in my first comment, but I worked before

Comment: Not sure. Edit that into your original question with the errors its producing. Comments don't format code that well.

Comment: @cschlum Pass `vectors[i]` and `vectors[j]` rather than `i` and `j` into the dot product function.

Comment: okay I tried that, the code does run (great!!) but it does not return the expected answer

Comment: Shift the max_product assignment and the return statement over one indent. Remember that indentation matters in Python!

Comment: it is still slightly off but I will eventually figure it out, thank you very much for your help!